# Proof about Infimum and supremum of sets

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I am working on the following exercise and I am almost done I think but got stuck in the end.I am looking for some hint:
“If A is not empty and bounded below, let B be the set of lower bounds for A. Prove that B is not empty, that B is bounded above and that the sup(B) is the inf(A).” Note: A and B are sets of real numbers in any case.
My current answer is :
Since A is bounded below, there are lower bounds for A so B is not empty by definition. Moreover, since the elements in B are by definition lower bounds of A, in particular any element of A will serve as an upper bound for the set of lower bounds, B. Hence B is bounded above. Finally, by the least upper bound property, since B is not empty and bounded above, sup(B) exists. Let * = sup(B).
By definition, * >= l for all lower bounds for A. Now, from here we cannot conclude directly that * is a lower bound for A, since perhaps * is also greater than all a in A. Now, suppose that * > a for all a in A. Then, since * is the sup(B), there is a lower bound l of A such that l > a. However this contradicts the fact that l is a lower bound for the set A. Hence, this proves that * is a lower bound for A. Now, the second and final part to show that * is the inf(A) should be to demonstrate that given any number x < * , there is some number a in A satisfying that a < x. However, I am not sure how to approach this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your justification of the existence of $\sup(B)$ looks good.

Suppose for sake of contradiction that there exists $a \in A$ such that $a < \sup B$. By the definition of $\sup B$, there exists $b \in B$ satisfying $a < b < \sup B$. This is a contradiction, since $b \in B$ is a lower bound of $A$ (by definition of $B$), yet it is larger than the element $a$ of $A$.

Thus $\sup B$ is itself a lower bound for $A$. Since we already know that $\sup B$ is greater than or equal to all lower bounds of $A$, we can conclude $\sup B = \inf A$ (see the definition of an infimum).

Comment: I can see that recalling that * = sup(B) and combining it with the fact that * is a lower bound for A (as proven by contradiction before) tells us that b <= * <= a for all b in B and a in A. However I don’t see why we can conclude from here that the fact : if x < * then there is an a in A such that a < x is true.

Comment: I am not sure about the following thing, but from that combined inequality I said that then, any number x > * must satisfy that x > b for all lower bounds of A. Hence, x is not a lower bound of A (doesn’t belong to B) which means that there is some a in A smaller than x. This proves the second property that makes a number a  greatest lower bound and hence sup(B) is inf(A)